# Keras P/R metrics at different thresholds during training

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I'm training a binary classifier and I'd like to see Precision/Recall metrics at different thresholds.

Tensorflow 2.3 introduced [tf.keras.metrics.Precision](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Precision) and [tf.keras.metrics.Recall](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Recall) which take a `thresholds` parameter, where you can specify one or multiple thresholds for which you want the metrics computed. This all works as advertised i.e.

```
m = tf.keras.metrics.Precision(thresholds=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6])
m.update_state([0, 1, 0, 1], [0.4, 0.5, 0.3, 0.8])
m.result().numpy()
```

Returns the precision value at each threshold `[0.5, 0.5, 0.6666667, 1., 1., 1.]`, as per the documentation.

However when passed as metrics to `Model.compile` I get a single metric regardless of how many thresholds I have.

```
pr_thresholds = list(np.arange(0.05, 0.95, 0.05))
model.compile(
    'adam',
    'binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=[ 
        keras.metrics.Precision(thresholds=pr_thresholds),
        keras.metrics.Recall(thresholds=pr_thresholds),
    ]
)
```

I get

```
Epoch 34/50
395/395 [==============================] - 22s 54ms/step - loss: 0.4314 - precision: 0.7886 - recall: 0.9008 - val_loss: 0.5113 - val_precision: 0.7434 - val_recall: 0.8769
```

What's happening here ? Does it always use the default threshold value of 0.5 in this case ?

Is there a way I can get it to display the values for multiple thresholds during training ?

Comment: Can you please try: `metrics=[ 
        [keras.metrics.Precision(thresholds=pr_thresholds)],
        [keras.metrics.Recall(thresholds=pr_thresholds)],
    ]`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71098645/9987623

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the metrics value for each threshold along the fitting process if you explicitely instantiate the corresponding metric class for each threshold, as follows:

```
model.compile(
optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-2),
loss='categorical_crossentropy',
metrics=[metrics.Recall(thresholds=0.6), 
         metrics.Recall(thresholds=0.9)])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

and as you can see in the image below, for each epoch you can see that the first recall value (with threshold 0.6) is higher than the second one (threshold 0.9) as expected:

[image]

And for your case, to build the list of metrics objects programatically, where you can now see 3 recalls per epoch:

```
thresholds = [0.6, 0.7, 0.9]
metrics_objs_list=[metrics.Recall(thresholds=thr) for thr in thresholds]
```

[image]

Comment: That works but still doesn't explain what happens when you pass them as model metrics (it seems that the thresholds are indeed replaced by the default one - 0.5) or whether it is intended or not.

Comment: as from my tests, rather than taking the default 0.5, it seems to take the first one in the passed array, you can check it out and see if metric values also change (significantly) depending on the first threshold on the array... Whatever, that would not solve what you want either